# Multiple Shaders in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, webgl, shader

Is there a way to create multiple shaders (both vertex, fragment, even geometry and tessellation) that can be compounded in what they do?

For example: I've seen a number of uses of the **in** and **out** keywords in the later versions of OpenGL, and will use these to illustrate my question.

Is there a way given a shader (doesn't matter which, but let's say fragment shader) such as

```
in inVar;
out outVar;
void man(){
    var varOne = inVar;
    var varTwo = varOne;
    var varThr = varTwo;
    outVar = varThr;
}
```

To turn it into the fragment shader

```
in inVar;
out varOne;
void main(){
    varOne = inVar;
}
```

Followed by the fragment shader

```
in varOne;
out varTwo;
void main(){
    varTwo = varOne;
}
```

Followed by the fragment shader

```
in varTwo(
out varThr;
void main(){
    varThr = varTwo
}
```

And finally Followed by the fragment shader

```
in varThr;
out outVar;
void main(){
    outVar = varThr;
}
```

Are the **in** and **out** the correct "concepts" to describe this behavior or should I be looking for another keyword(s)?

Comment: Once created, glUsePogram(pgmID) allows you switch between programs

Comment: @j-p : What do you mean? I'm not trying to switch programs. I'm trying to combine the effects from multiple shaders of the same type.

Comment: there is GL `subroutines` that allows composition...https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Subroutine

Answer (score 11):

In OpenGL, you can attach multiple shaders of the same type to a program object. In OpenGL ES, this is not supported.

This is from the OpenGL 4.5 spec, section "7.3 Program Objects", page 88 (emphasis added):

> Multiple shader objects of the same type **may be** attached to a single program object, and a single shader object may be attached to more than one program object.

Compared with the OpenGL ES 3.2 spec, section "7.3 Program Objects", page 72 (emphasis added):

> Multiple shader objects of the same type **may not be** attached to a single program object. However, a single shader object may be attached to more than one program object.

However, even in OpenGL, using multiple shaders of the same type does not work they way you outline it in your question. Only one of the shaders can have a `main()`. The other shaders typically only contain functions. So your idea of chaining multiple shaders of the same type into a pipeline will not work in this form.

The way this is sometimes used is that there is one (or multiple) shaders that contain a collection of generic functions, which only needs to be compiled once, and can then be used for multiple shader programs. This is comparable to a library of functions in general programming. You could call this, using unofficial terminology, a "library shader".

Then each shader program has a single shader of each type containing a `main()`, and that shader contains the specific logic and control flow for that program, while calling generic functions from the "library shaders".

Following the outline in your question, you could achieve something similar with defining a function in each shader. For example, the first fragment shader could contain this code:

```
void shaderOne(in vec4 varIn, out vec4 varOut) {
    varOut = varIn;
}
```

Second shader:

```
void shaderTwo(in vec4 varIn, out vec4 varOut) {
    varOut = varIn;
}
```

Third shader:

```
void shaderThr(in vec4 varIn, out vec4 varOut) {
    varOut = varIn;
}
```

Then you need one shader with a `main()`, where you can chain the other shaders:

```
in vec4 varOne;
out vec4 outVar;

void main() {
    vec4 varTwo, varThr;
    shaderOne(varOne, varTwo);
    shaderTwo(varTwo, varThr);
    shaderThr(varThr, outVar);
}
```

Comment: I was more concerned about enabling / disabling individual shaders (choosing which are applied) from the client. Doing as you describe would necessitate adding a bunch of **uniform** variables and prefixing each shader call with an **if/then** statement. And I don't think I would be able to say disable the **shaderTwo** call without it affecting **shaderThr**. In short I was wondering if I could modify the code example you gave to say disable the shaderCalls, thereby altering the effect but not giving an error when calling subsequent shader calls

Comment: I'm unaware of OpenGL supporting multiple shaders of the same type on a single program object. Can you please point that feature out? As far as I know at most OpenGL supports passing multiple strings but those strings are just concatenated. No reason not to concatenate them yourself which is what WebGL requires

Comment: @gman I added spec quotes close to the top of the post. I checked as far back as the 2.1 spec, and it has always been this way. I've seen this used in very successful games.

Comment: Thanks. So if I understand correctly it basically has no point whatsoever. It's functionally equivalent to string concat and a single shader. The only thing you might get out of it is precompilation of small snippets but I suspect no driver actually does that. No wonder it was removed in ES.

Comment: @gman Yes, saving compilation time is the only real benefit I see over concatenating the strings. Other than that, it might be more convenient depending on how your software is architected. Since it's used by major games, I suspect that they saw a benefit. The shared shaders containing functions can be fairly large.

Comment: @gman correct I guess a string concat is a good way to think about it, but with the addendum that you are concatting variables that may may either have values or may be empty i.e. Zero length or a single space. This can alter the string that is the end result.

Answer (score 4):

Generate your shaders. That's what pretty much all 3D engines and game engines do.

In other words they manipulate text using code and generate source code at runtime or build time.

Sometimes they use GLSL's preprocessor. Example

```
#ifdef USE_TEXTURE
  uniform sampler2D u_tex;
  varying vec2 v_texcoord;
#else
  uniform vec4 u_color;
#endif

void main() {
  #ifdef USE_TEXTURE
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_tex, v_texcoord);
  #else 
    gl_FragColor = u_color;
  #endif
}
```

Then at runtime prepend a string to define `USE_TEXTURE`.

JavaScript

```
var prefix = useLighting ? '#define USE_TEXTURE' : '';
var shaderSource = prefix + originalShaderSource;
```

Most engines though do a lot more string manipulation by taking lots of small chunks of GLSL and combining them with various string substitutions.

Comment: But pre-processors wouldn't allow for changing which shaders get applied or the order j. Which they get applied after the actual shader is compiled. My main goal is to do these things after both the client program and the individual shaders have been compiled (say through input selection)

Comment: That's now how shaders work. Generate your shaders. Whether you use the preprocessor to help with that or not is up to you.